# Using 'rpm -i' to install a package on CentOS6 but getting dependency error, even though I have installed the dependency, why?

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, rpm, sqlite

**Operating System = CentOS 6**

I'm trying to install a package as follows:

```
rpm -i package_name.rpm
```

But I get the following error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
sqlite >= 3.7.15 is needed by package_name
```

However, I've already installed the required dependency as follows:

Opened a browser and navigate to https://www.sqlite.org/download.html, downloaded sqlite-autoconf-3240000.tar.gz and extracted the files:

Then:

```
cd sqlite-autoconf-3240000
./configure --prefix = /usr/local
./configure 
make
make install
```

I verify that sqlite3 is working as follows:

```
[root@MyMachine home]# sqlite3
SQLite version 3.24.0 2018-06-04 19:24:41
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've installed the *program*, not the *dependency*. The package_name RPM specifies a dependency on the sqlite *RPM*, not the sqlite *program*.

Either install the sqlite RPM (after removing your manually-installed one) or tell RPM to ignore the dependencies while installing package_name: `rpm -i --nodeps package_name.rpm`.

Comment: Thank you, very good explanation. I actually got around the sqlite dependency error by doing an rpm -i older_sqlite_version.rpm and then doing an rpm -U older_sqlite_version.rpm before finally doing an rpm -i package_name.rpm which sorted my issues. I appreciate your help, I have a lot to learn about installing software on Unix like systems.